# Type=text pattern issue

Tags: java, javascript, html, xhtml

I am working on a small home project and need some help.  I created a test website and everything seems to work fine but I would like to add something to my user id field.
The question is

Can I add more than one item for the 
Type=text pattern="abc.*" field

What i mean is that can i add let's say 123 as a valid pattern for the user id field so the user can login with an id whose first 3 characters begin with EITHER abc OR 123 and the webpage will know its a valid id?

I tried 
type=text pattern="[abc.*][123.*]

but it doesn't seen to accept either one only both

Thanks!

Mike R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your can use Or (|) operators, like

pattern="[abc.]|[123.]"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Whenever I try to put the example you stated it will only let me type in a OR 1 and anything after is flagged Invalid.  Am I still doing something Wrong?

Comment: no, you just need create your regular expression smarter

Comment: Got it finally!  Thanks you are awesome User3334707